# Removing code duplication in ruby

Tags: ruby, coding-style

Is there a cleaner way to write this ? I don't like that code duplication.

```
# Adds the content of two arrays except the first cell because the first cell is a string
# The arrays don't have to be the same length.
# * *Args*  :
#  - +a+ -> first array
#  - +b+ -> second array
#
def add_array(a,b)
  if a.size >= b.size then
    a.map.with_index{ |m,i|if i != 0 then m + b[i].to_i else m end}
  else
    b.map.with_index{ |m,i|if i != 0 then m + a[i].to_i else m end}
  end
end
```

Input example :

```
arr1 = ["foo",1,2,3,4,5]
arr2 = []
arr3 = ["foo",2,4,6,5,7,8,9,4,5,6]


arr2 =  add_array(arr1, arr2)
puts arr2.inspect
arr2 = add_array(arr2, arr3)
puts arr2.inspect
```

Output :

```
["foo", 1, 2 ,3 ,4 ,5]
["foo", 3, 6, 9, 9, 12, 8, 9, 4, 5, 6]
```

Feel free to comment / criticize and express your imagination!

Thanks.

Comment: Give one example input and the output,may be we can give a better code than yours..

Comment: @Babai examples added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step:

```
def add_array(a,b)
  if a.size > b.size then
    a.map.with_index{ |m, i| if i != 0 then m + b[i].to_i else m end}
  else
    add_array(b, a)
  end
end
```

Comment: Yes, so obvious but I didn't think about it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

With my humble novice opinion;

```
def add_array(a,b)
  a, b = b, a if b.size > a.size
  a.map.with_index{ |m,i|if i != 0 then m + b[i].to_i else m end}
end
```

Edit: Polonium's suggestion is better.

Comment: I've always been told that ternary conditionals are a bad habit as they are difficult to understand to someone who didn't write the code and who has to modify it. What do you think? (anyway, I like your solution ;) )

Comment: I don't think they're always bad, but here you can swap that line with something like: a,b = b,a if b.size > a.size

Answer (score 1):

```
def add_array(a,b)
  a.map.with_index { |m, i| i.zero? && m || m + choose(a, b)[i].to_i }
end

def choose(a, b)
  if a.size > b.size
    b
  else
    a
  end
end
```

Pulling the choice of order for the array based on size means that you can use it other places.

Removing the if negative is something I strive for.

All of the sample data was already integers, but I left the coercion to integer there.

Answer (score 1):

```
def add_array(a,b)
  a.size > b.size ? merge_arrays(a,b) : merge_arrays(b,a)
end

def merge_arrays(a,b)
 a.map.with_index{ |m,i|if i != 0 then m + b[i].to_i else m end}
end
```

In this case, the check on array size is done only once. I introduced that new function to ensure that it is a bit more readable.